# JavaLite Vs Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, activejdbc, javalite

I just started to learn javalite but I don't understand if javalite is more benificial and light weight than hibernate still most of the projects are working on hibernate why?
and can we use javalite for large enterprise application.if anyone using javalite please let me know pros and cons of javlite w.r.t hibernate.

thank's

Comment: waiting for answer please reply.

Answer (score 1):

JavaLite is more than just an ORM, it includes an entire ecosystem for building apps, including: ActiveJDBC (ORM), ActiveWeb (web framework), DB-Migrator(for database migrations), JavaLite HTTP (web client for web services), Async (JMS processing), AppConfig (configuration of apps for different environments), builr-in logging, query statistics, and more I'm probably missing now. ActiveJDBC is easier to use and faster at runtime than Hibernate, and JavaLite used by many companies to build log lasting enterprise apps. Hibernate is more popular because it is older and there are books written about it.

If you want to build an app with Hibernate, you would still need to pull in various other technologies, such as Spring MVC (or equivalent) and a bunch of others, integrate them together, etc.

JavaLite is a one stop  framework with all pieces integrated and tuned for fast development and runtime execution.